# power shell two dimensional array comparison error

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to compare two arrays and want to delete duplicate values.  Here's the code I've got:

```
if(($run -ne $null) -and ($data -ne $null)) {       
    $remains = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $data -DifferenceObject $run -PassThru
    echo "$remains" 
}
```

and the variables contains the following data, although `$run` contains data it is still alerting error.

`$data` - Two dimensional array

```
[d13 , m0051]
[d13 , m0052]
[d21 , m0083]
[d21 , m0084]
[d26 , m0103]
[d33 , m0131]
[d33 , m0132]
[d34 , m0136]
```

`$run` - Two dimensional array

```
[d13 , m0052]
[d21 , m0084]
[d26 , m0103]
[d33 , m0132]
[d34 , m0136]
```

Error:

```
Compare-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'DifferenceObject' because it is null.
At e:\b.ps1:84 char:70
+             $remains = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $data -DifferenceObject <<<<  $run -PassThru
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Compare-Object], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CompareObje
   ctCommand
```

Any idea where the problem is?  I've tried Googling and spent a lot of time on this before posting this.

Answer (score 0):

How did you create $run and $data?

Here is how I gave it a try:

```
$run = @()
$run += ,@("d13", "m0051")
$run += ,@("d13", "m0052")
$run += ,@("d21", "m0083")
$run += ,@("d21", "m0084")
$run += ,@("d26", "m0103")
$run += ,@("d33", "m0131")
$run += ,@("d34", "m0136")

$data = @()
$data += ,@("d13", "m0052")
$data += ,@("d21", "m0084")
$data += ,@("d26", "m0103")
$data += ,@("d33", "m0132")
$data += ,@("d34", "m0136")
if(($run -ne $null) -and ($data -ne $null)) {       
    $remains = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $data -DifferenceObject $run -PassThru
    write-output $remains
}
```

Output is 4 elements

```
d13
m0051
d21
m0083
d33
m0131
d33
m0132
```

Comment: am reading data from file. am not able to attach files here. thanks for quick response

Comment: sorry but i found out that the error lies in initializing variable, because i recursively used it. Now the issue is fixed. thank you very much for the efforts.